# Taylor diagram size, color, save argument?

Tags: r, ggplot2, save, size, taylor-series

**I generated Taylor diagram** [image]
**using library:**

```
library(plotrix)
library(rJava)
library(xlsxjars)
library(readxl)
library(xlsx)
```

and data used `dput(df)`

```
structure(list(Pb = c(12.54, 12.53, 13.57, 19.22, 22.27, 18.37, 
19, 14.34, 16.35), Boruta_XGBoost = c(8.89136409759521, 8.85756206512451, 
8.21786308288574, 12.9624891281128, 13.2968854904175, 12.7977981567383, 
12.3957328796387, 9.69775390625, 11.781777381897), Boruta_SVM = c(12.8297886877439, 
14.1176611943491, 14.9879296831078, 18.1703565549757, 19.5840584003096, 
18.8792561701891, 16.2778795502105, 13.4901086669503, 14.2836465797069
), Boruta_RF = c(14.3177444444444, 11.1845266666667, 10.8805244444444, 
17.6771022222222, 20.7142466666667, 18.5657155555556, 16.8954355555556, 
12.9909844444444, 15.9368244444444), GA_XGBoost = c(8.90407180786133, 
8.7996244430542, 8.19470405578613, 12.927845954895, 13.1713933944702, 
12.896990776062, 12.4013185501099, 9.44187641143799, 11.9617586135864
), GA_SVM = c(14.5574045001675, 14.7111528658119, 14.5103784219767, 
17.6100336774524, 19.0957864342351, 17.836320761182, 15.7884998778531, 
13.2352198846198, 14.7596456378561), GA_RF = c(13.7602755555556, 
11.43164, 10.6581822222222, 18.0504933333333, 20.8309088888889, 
18.5738422222222, 16.5107822222222, 12.9161022222222, 15.53854
), XGBoost_XGBoost = c(8.42767715454102, 8.02925300598145, 7.27468395233154, 
12.2474374771118, 13.0366401672363, 13.088475227356, 12.264874458313, 
8.62850284576416, 10.4450559616089), XGBoost_SVM = c(13.0668720920662, 
11.9439605396003, 12.2892781235256, 18.9685052474489, 22.1775370825045, 
18.5729878124879, 18.412140924591, 13.7120185862238, 15.2216196143028
), XGBoost_RF = c(12.5330444444444, 12.6012, 10.6674022222222, 
17.7389044444445, 20.4518844444445, 18.4774088888889, 17.0711288888889, 
12.8564933333333, 14.4656444444444)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**using below code:**

```
taylor.diagram(Actual,
               Boruta_XGBoost,
               add=FALSE,
               col="#FFFF33", #the color for the points displayed.
               pch=19, #the type of point to display.
               #For Color: ("#FFFFFF" = White, “#990000” = Red) see more:- http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Colors_(ggplot2)/

               pos.cor=TRUE,
               xlab="Standard deviation (Normalized)", 
               ylab="Standard deviation (Normalized)", 
               main="Taylor Diagram of all applied models Vs Actual",

               show.gamma=TRUE, #whether to display standard deviation arcs around the reference point (only for pos.cor=TRUE).
               ngamma=4, #the number of gammas to display (default=3).
               gamma.col = "red", #color to use for the gamma arcs (only with pos.cor=TRUE).

               sd.arcs=3, #whether to display arcs along the standard deviation axes.
               ref.sd=TRUE, #whether to display the arc representing the reference standard deviation.
               sd.method=TRUE, #Whether to use the sample or estimated population SD.
               grad.corr.lines = c(0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,0.9), #the values for the radial lines for correlation values

               pcex=2.8, cex.axis=1.8, cex.lab=2.2, #pcex for size of 'pch'; cex.axis for size of tick; 
               normalize=TRUE, #whether to normalize the models so that the reference has a standard deviation of 1.
               mar=c(5,6,5,10), #margin=( bottom, left, top, right); only apply for pos.cor = TRUE plot

               lwd=10,
               font=6,
               lty=1)
```

**My quarries are:**

1. why the size of x-axis-label is not increasing?, however, I used `cex.sub` the argument as well.
2. how to increase the size of gamma and sd.arc line?
3. how to change the color of sd.arc line?
4. how to save this graph in an editable file?; however, I used `library(officer)` but did not workout
5. Don't we have ggplot2 for the same? if yes then, please share
6. Any single answer to the single question would be appreciated as well.
   many thanks!

Comment: Please identify any packages used.

Comment: Also, sample data is needed if not included in the package. I tried the `plotrix` package, but get `Error in is.data.frame(y) : object 'Boruta_XGBoost' not found`

Comment: thank you! I added the library and data used, please find above

Comment: The data provided includes the `Boruta_XGBoost` but not `Actual`. Is that maybe the `Pb` column?

Comment: I did duplicate your chart using `taylor.diagram(df$Pb, df$Boruta_XGBoost,...`

Comment: @markhogue, Pb is the Actual data.

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer. Answers by quarry number in the question:

1. Your code `cex.lab=2.2` is working. I changed it to `cex.lab=1` and got very noticeable differences. Ditto for the other `cex` options.

2 - 3. These are not options in the function. However, what you can do is copy the code for the function from here: https://github.com/plotrix/plotrix/blob/master/R/taylor.diagram.R and change what you want, save it as your own function. For example, in the segment annotated " # add the axes", change the color option to `col = "red"` or whatever.

4. I don't know what you mean by an editable plot. Maybe someone else can address.
5. Search of https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/index.html results in nothing matching "taylor", so I don't think so.